# Using GridView and LinearLayout , Gridview is expressed in the top on display

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, gridview

I am designing layout as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
<ScrollView 
    <LinearLayout
        <LinearLayout
            <TextViewなど
            .
            .
            .
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            <packagename.ExpandableHeightGridView
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I was executing the program on the nexus5.
It is as follows, Gridview is expressed in the top on display.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrkGQ.png)

If I scroll to the top, then LinearLayout is expressed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM2EF.png)

I tried to adjust the layout.
But GridView wasn't adjusted.
I want to set LinearLayout to the top at first.

```
public class Activity_CommunicationSpace_MemberList extends Activity {

private List<Data_User> objects = new ArrayList<Data_User>();
private Data_User item = new Data_User();
private String user_name;
private Bitmap user_icon;
private Bitmap user_profile;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_communicationspace_memberlist);

    user_name = "Test_Test";
    user_icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon_lamborghini);

    for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        item = new Data_User();
        item.setNameData(user_name);
        item.setIconData(user_icon);
        objects.add(item);
    }

    Adapter_CommunicationSpace_MemberList adapter = new Adapter_CommunicationSpace_MemberList(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.adapter_communicationspace_memberlist, objects);
    ExpandableHeightGridView expandableHeightGridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_communicationspace_memberlist);
    expandableHeightGridView.setExpanded(true);
    expandableHeightGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.activity_communicationspace_memberlist_scrollView);
    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post full xml.

Comment: why gridview inside scroll view without fix height?

Answer (score 0):

If Listview And Gridview Are in Bottom Then its Scroll itself. they Does'nt need Scrollview or ExpendeableGridview in This Case
U Should Try This Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Country Codes"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/findSelected"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Get Selected Items" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"/></LinearLayout>
```